# Callbacks are slow from com server

Tags: c#, com, callback, com-interop

I am using a native COM server from a .Net C# application

Everything works fine except that callbacks from the COM server into the .Net application gradually becomes slower. The server and .Net application is always running on the same machine.

Calling from .Net to the COM server is always fast.

The strange thing is that it doesn't happen on all computers even if they run the same binaries.

I have spent a lot of time on this issue. Compared environments where the callbacks are fast with ones where it is slow without finding anything special.

- The callbacks start fast but get exponentially slower over time.
- Doesn't matter if the callbacks are assigned to .Net methods or not.
  (There is a server switch to turn all callbacks off. That is how I know the problem is with the callbacks)
- The slow computers use Window 7 64-bit but the same configuration is fast on other computers.
- There are slow and fast computers on the same domain and network
- Doesn't matter if the user is local admin or standard user
- I have monitored Disk/Network activity but there is no difference between slow and fast
- There is no noticeable difference in memory consumption
- Looked at CLR memory from WinDbg but found nothing strange

Some things I have noted:

- The server process use 100% CPU when the callbacks are slow.
- Looked at the call stack with process explorer and the server is most of the time in one of the RPC Ndr* functions, i.e. [NdrClientCall2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I am now out of ideas and need some help to solve this.